# GSuite Admin API no longer working for user updates

Tags: coldfusion, google-api-java-client, google-workspace

I have some code that is using the Java G Suite Admin API SDK.  It is driven by Adobe ColdFusion and has been working for 4-5 years now.  Suddenly, I am getting errors that don't make sense.  It seems like it is not connecting and creating the necessary objects or something has changed with the object requirements that I am not aware of.  I looked at the documentation online and nothing seems to have changed.

Up until about a week ago, it has been working fine.  Then I started to get more errors, now I don't seem to be able to make any API updates.

When password changes are attempted, the error that is returned from ColdFusion states that:

> The `setPassword` method was not found.::Either there are no methods
>   with the specified method name and argument types or the `setPassword`
>   method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot
>   decipher reliably. ColdFusion found `0 methods` that match the provided
>   arguments. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method
>   exists, use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity.

When I attempt to create an email account I get :

> Not known

I'm not even certain where to start troubleshooting.  Is it possible that my admin account key expired?

Comment: Has the code changed? Did you apply any updates recently (CF, java, etc)? Also, please post the code throwing the error.

Comment: I think I figured out what happened.  No, the code had not changed at all and no updates to the CF or Java software.  I did a bunch more testing and found out that I was getting a Javax SSL exception error.  No idea what might have caused it, but it is working again.  I did submit a support ticket with Google and received only one reply.  The only thing that I found online was a TLS error.  I have gone in to make certain that TLS 1.0 and 1.1 had been disabled, as well as SSL 3.0, etc.  Shortly after checking those it started working again.  I did not restart the server yet. but it is working.

Comment: I still am not certain of the cause of the issue or if something was wrong at Google and has been remedied.  I have not had any further responses to my ticket yet.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what was the javax exception? If you're *certain* you didn't make any changes, could be they fixed a problem with a cert on their side (expired, etc...)  and that is why it "resolved itself". Knowing the details might help someone else in the future. Anyway, glad it is working again :-)

Comment: Apparently I was wrong.  I has been working okay for several days and now it is failing continuously again.  I had disabled TLS 1.0 & 1.1, but that killed another application's connectivity so I had to re-enable them.
The error I'm getting from my Coldfusion server is  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException - in ....
     Received fatal alert: decrypt_error
I am using Admin Directory API Client Library for Java 1.2.0.
Google doesn't support the APIs so won't assist beyond giving me a link to these forums.  So I don't know if something has changed at the API servers.

Comment: BTW, the time between re-enabling TLS and when the Java API started giving me errors was about a day and a half.

Comment: Look at the rest of the error message, because there are different causes of a SSLHandshakeException. You can also enable verbose debugging in your jvm.config file by adding `-Djavax.net.debug=ALL` and restarting the cf server . Bear in mind it's VERY detailed, so it'll generate a lot of logs, but should give you enough detail to decipher what's causing the error.

Comment: Thanks.  I have made that change to the server, but I will have to wait until tomorrow morning to restart the server.  Will update after some testing.